# Playing Audio recorded on BlackBerry externally

Tags: blackberry, audio, amr

I have a BB app that records and sends audio to a web service and is stored as a BLOB on my DB. I would like to know how I can play this audio from another source that isn't the BB player. I am able to save the audio data as a byte array on the BB and then extract it and play it without problem but i can't manage to do the same when I try to play it using Java Sound for instance. Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlackBerry records files in AMR format. Java Sound cannot play them back, you need a codec for that. Try, for example, http://sourceforge.net/projects/jspeex/, if you want to stay pure Java.

Comment: Don't want to stay pure java necessarily, the java sound thing is just for testing to see if i receive the audio correctly. The end of this would be to grab that audio file and play it on a browser. Any idea how i can do this? Like an embeded audio player i can use ? Thx for the answer btw, i will test this out

Comment: Is there any simple example i can't seem to find a simple introduction and besides the javadoc on the site there doesn't seem to be much, what i want to do is fairly simple, i think, just grab a byte[] array and play it

Comment: Oh, then you can just install [RetroCode](http://sourceforge.net/projects/retrocode/files/) and do `code input_file_name.amr output_file_name.wav` 
Also keep in mind that most of the source code in these tools comes from FFmpeg - the most comprehensive opensource code library for this kind of stuff.

Comment: As for playing it in the browser - I am not an expert in this area (sound playback in DHTML), but I imagine a combination of HTML5 and Flash (for something like IE6, there are plenty of freely available ones) will do the trick, as long as you convert the files into mp3 first.

Comment: I've changed how I store my sound files, I no longer save them as a BLOB in my DB since this would cause serious strain on my DB server under heavy traffic, also it makes it difficult to play the files on a website since I have to pull the data from it, turn it into a file and then play it. 

So what I do now is that when the the petition to save the note arrives at my web service I make the .amr file and save it in a folder. So now I know the sound I send is properly received. Since finding an amr player doesn't seem easy, any idea how I can write a script that will convert my files?

Comment: Forgot to mention that in my DB i save the URL to the file. Also thx alot for taking the time to answer my questions.

Comment: I'm looking to the FFmpeg library you mentioned I checked jFFmpeg but it does not support the amr format, or at least it is not listed on the site. Any idea how I can use the commands from the library in java? Or maybe php at least so I so can run it on the web client side?